# How to display too broad table? Not fit to one page as a normal-sized

Tags: positioning

[image]

I use the KOMA-script (`sudo apt-get install koma-script` -- suggests you the thing in Ubuntu). I think options:

1. make font even smaller (eg with KOMA -script)
2. make it on two pages, perhaps [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper)
3. make it vertical?
4. other?

**My code**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=7pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
<<echo=False>>=
library(xtable)
...
xtable(maDat)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hence it is not (La)TeX, could you add a note, what `xtable` is, please?

Comment: What you wrote in your comment, should you have stated already in your question.

Comment: @Speravir: sorry hassle, will look more closely to this soon. Perhaps, you have some point here, cannot yet understand.

Answer (score 1):

These are the possibilities:

1. Enlarge the particular page

   ```
   \enlargethispage{by amount}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \addtolength{\footskip}{-17pt}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{0.7cm}
   \addtolength{\textwidth}{0.3cm}
   ```
2. Use `fullpage` package.
3. Reduce margins for the particular page.
4. Use a smaller font (`\small` or `\footnotesize`) if you are ok with it.
5. Use landsacpe page mode...........

Note: your option 2 is ok with length but with width of the table, things get really nasty.

Comment: You can try to use `sidewaystable`, and/or a `scalebox`.

Comment: what about to display vertically the table? I tried to rotate the table by `\rotatebox{90}{...}` from graphicx but not working for some reason. Followed this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table) but I have `\begin{table}...\end{table}` -env, generated by xtable.

Comment: @hhh: Perhaps package `rotating`? Compare my answer to another, quite weird problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50385/9237.